# magento custom attribute layout

Tags: php, magento, attributes

there are some problem with Magento attribute customization section when I tried to edit the product. It appears like the previous developer had created the whole attribute for the colors (as I have attached the picture)

[image]

I would like to change them all so I took a guess and went to change the file view.phtml under the path app/design/frontend/default/default/catalog/product/

However, only the list of colors are changed on the backend but the color attribute list still remains the same.

Does anybody have a clue or has anybody ever dealt with this before?
I might need to search through the core engine file? I don't wanna touch that part of the website at all.

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

1. check the attributes and attribute sets ? It maybe store the attribute value in admin page: Catalog -> Attributes
2. check this module has database tables which maybe store the attribute value (*)

and I found you changed the front end view.html file, but did not change the back end one.

*Optional - It probably has many customize modules in this Magento, you might want to see the code of module to know how these value been stored or how this module work

Comment: thank you for your advices. It seems that the previous developer didn't really organize his coding so well so that I decided to make every single thing from scratch again.

Comment: @scottymorg have you checked the attributes or tables? how is the result?  if you can confirm these functions come with modules, you probably need to find the code that give those color options.

Comment: I just did the detailed search and I found out that the code is in app/design/adminhtml/ path everything in the backend are coded there.